# JavaScript: Create object with nested properties from string split by specific character

Tags: javascript, string, object, split, transform

How to use the `name` property in this object:

```
const obj = {
  name: 'root/branch/subbranch/leaf',
  value: 'my-value'
}
```

To create an object with the following format:

```
{
  root: {
    branch: {
      subbranch: {
        leaf: 'my-value'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There's no built-in function, if that is the question.

Comment: @xehpuk yeah you're right. I'm just looking for a smarter way to go about this, as I think my own implementation could be improved.

Comment: What is your own implementation?

Comment: You didn't post your implementation.

Comment: @xehpuk my implementation was too hacky haha rather not post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this using [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const obj = {
  name: 'root/branch/subbranch/leaf',
  value: 'my-value'
}


let newObj = {}
const parts = obj.name.split('/')
parts.reduce((prev, curr, i) => (
  Object.assign(
    prev, 
    {[curr]: i === parts.length - 1 ? obj.value : Object(prev[curr])}
  ), 
  prev[curr]
), newObj)

console.log(newObj)
```

Comment: `reduce` is not a good fit here, because (1) it's impure and (2) the return value is discarded.

Comment: This works perfectly for the large object set I am processing. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/antoniobrandao/ykej5tbq/3/

Comment: I'm selecting this answer because it performed better in my benchmarks and because it is vanilla JS. Helped my learn about array `reduce`. Thanks CJ

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a reciursive function and a wrapper to call it.

```js
const obj = {
  name: 'root/branch/subbranch/leaf',
  value: 'my-value'
}

const recursiveNest = (result, value, arr, index = 0) => { 
  const path = arr[index]
  if (index < arr.length - 1) {
      result[path] = {}
      index +=1;
      recursiveNest(result[path], value, arr, index)
  } else {
      result[arr[index]] = value; 
  }
};

const createNestedObject = (obj, splitBy) => {
   let result = {}
   recursiveNest(result, obj.value, obj.name.split(splitBy))
   return result;
}

console.log(createNestedObject(obj, '/'));
```

Answer (score 0):

[Lodash](https://lodash.com) provides [`setWith(object, path, value, [customizer])`](https://lodash.com/docs/#setWith):

```js
const obj = {
  name: 'root/branch/subbranch/leaf',
  value: 'my-value'
}

console.log(_.setWith({}, obj.name.split('/'), obj.value, _.stubObject))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, looks great for being so compact! Although it works for this particular object, somehow it doesn't work for the large object set I am working with: https://jsfiddle.net/antoniobrandao/5xntm268/2/. But the solution by @Cjmarkham works: https://jsfiddle.net/antoniobrandao/ykej5tbq/3/

Comment: Neither display anything but `"Running fiddle"` to me in the console. Works fine for me when I run it in my browser though.

Comment: should appear in the console, the output is via console.dir

Comment: see the "color_palletes" object contents

Comment: I see what you mean. The numerical parts "tricked" Lodash into creating arrays instead of objects. Updated my answer to use `setWith` with `stubObject` instead.